# How to parse yesod-form parameters into Haskell values

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

The code below is from the Home.hs file created by the yesod-simple scaffold.
I like to do simple string manipulation on text input but don't know how to parse it into a Text value.
How, for example, can I use toUpper on fileDescription?
I've tried using lookupPostParam
but I'm struggling with it's type signature:

```
lookupPostParam :: MonadHandler m => Text -> m (Maybe Text)
```

*Home.hs*

```
module Handler.Home where

import Import
import Yesod.Form.Bootstrap3 (BootstrapFormLayout (..), renderBootstrap3)
import Text.Julius (RawJS (..))

data FileForm = FileForm
    { fileInfo :: FileInfo
    , fileDescription :: Text
    }

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    (formWidget, formEnctype) <- generateFormPost sampleForm
    let submission = Nothing :: Maybe FileForm
        handlerName = "getHomeR" :: Text
    defaultLayout $ do
        let (commentFormId, commentTextareaId, commentListId) = commentIds
        aDomId <- newIdent
        setTitle "Welcome To Yesod!"
        $(widgetFile "homepage")

postHomeR :: Handler Html
postHomeR = do
    ((result, formWidget), formEnctype) <- runFormPost sampleForm
    let handlerName = "postHomeR" :: Text
        submission = case result of
            FormSuccess res -> Just res
            _ -> Nothing

    defaultLayout $ do
        let (commentFormId, commentTextareaId, commentListId) = commentIds
        aDomId <- newIdent
        setTitle "Welcome To Yesod!"
        $(widgetFile "homepage")

sampleForm :: Form FileForm
sampleForm = renderBootstrap3 BootstrapBasicForm $ FileForm
    <$> fileAFormReq "Choose a file"
    <*> areq textField textSettings Nothing
    where textSettings = FieldSettings
            { fsLabel = "What's on the file?"
            , fsTooltip = Nothing
            , fsId = Nothing
            , fsName = Nothing
                 , fsAttrs =
                    [ ("class", "form-control")
                    , ("placeholder", "File description")
                    ]
            }

commentIds :: (Text, Text, Text)
commentIds = ("js-commentForm", "js-createCommentTextarea", "js-
commentList")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately a fault in documentation and communication.

Given

```
lookupPostParam :: (MonadResource m, MonadHandler m) => Text -> m (Maybe Text)
```

the reader is meant to infer that `m` is not only a `MonadResouce` and a `MonadHandler` but also `Monad`. This tiny little line of code packs up a lot of intent into a very small sentence; it's a wart that so much of Haskell library usage is left implicit and subtextual. For example, to call `toUpper` on the `Text` inside this type you are meant to do this:

```
{-# language OverloadedStrings #-}
foo :: (MonadResource m, MonadHandler m) => m (Maybe Text)
foo = do
  valueMaybe <- lookupPostParam "key"
  case valueMaybe of
    Just value ->
      pure (toUpper value)
    Nothing ->
      Nothing
```

Note that the monad stack (`MonadHandler`, `MonadResource`) has "infected" your code. This is meant to be intentional, so as to constrain you via the type checker to only run this function in the intended Yesod environment/state machine/context/whatever.

### However

You are using yesod-forms and it would be nice to do the same thing within that framework. As with `lookupPostParam`, we can take advantage of the monad-applicative-functor typeclasses.

We can adapt this to the `Form FileForm` value that you have.

```
sampleForm :: AForm Handler FileForm
sampleForm =
  FileForm <$> fileAFormReq "Choose a file"
           <*> (toUpper <$> areq textField textSettings Nothing)
```

I think the types of `yesod-forms` changed between releases. I'm copying my types off the latest version as of writing, 1.4.11.

Here we take advantage of the [`Monad m => Functor (AForm m)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-form-1.4.11/docs/Yesod-Form-Types.html#t:AForm) instance. Knowing that we are indeed in a monad (the `Handler` monad) means we can use `fmap` and its infixed sibling `<$>` on the value returned by `areq textField textSettings Nothing`. This allows us to lift arbitrary functions acting on `Text` into the `AForm m` stack. For example, here we went from `Text -> Text` to `AForm Handler Text -> AForm Handler Text`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I copied the type of lookupPostParam somewhere on the web: next time I will use the hackage site for that, but I don't know how to find the version of yesod-form I've installed. The command 'stack exec -- yesod version' returns yesod-bin 1.5.2.3. Installation is conform the quick start guide, on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system.
I've tried your suggestions but still got 'Couldn't match expected type' errors. However your answer gave me several hints to look further, so I clicked the checkmark. Thanks!

Comment: I got that off of https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.33/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:lookupPostParam but I think you figured it out already; to find out what version package you're using with stack try `stack list-dependencies`